# Kinect for Ubuntu users

Tags: hardware, games, kinect

I have a few questions relating to Microsoft's Kinect or similar [motion detection device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_sensing) with comparable quality (further only Kinect) and Ubuntu:

- Is there a way to use Kinect controllers with Ubuntu?
- If so, is there any way to play games with Kinect on Ubuntu?
- Where can I find more information on how to configure games to use Kinect controllers, or development efforts for input drivers or games that support Kinect controllers?

Comment: Drivers exist for the Kinect device under Ubuntu (see [here](http://openkinect.org/wiki/Getting_Started)), but the only Kinect games I'm aware of to-date have been released for the Xbox 360.  I don't know that there are even any Windows-based Kinect games at this point.

Comment: Given that Wine doesn't even support regular Xbox360 controllers properly, it will probably take a long while till the official Kinect API is properly supported in Wine and usable for Windows Kinect software.

Comment: There are barely enough Linux games at all, let alone games that use the Kinect or any sensors like it.

Comment: @UriHerrera But it's possible to create some game with poor graphics and later with rich graphics (using some libraries, like [OSG](http://www.openscenegraph.org/projects/osg). It's possible that something is already in development.

Answer (score 1):

There are some interesting projects using WebGL and Kinect in a cross platform environment. Check out some of those with a google search --> [Kinect and the Web Browser](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&sugexp=frgbld&gs_nf=1&tok=6v4FiSoWHB626WKusj494A&cp=7&gs_id=x&xhr=t&q=webgl+kinect&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&oq=webgl+k&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=5d409e11edb055e4&biw=1440&bih=788)